# How to debug a class library in .NET 4.5.1 whose dll is in GAC

Tags: .net, debugging, .net-4.5, gac

I have a class library whose dll is present in GAC. I put the pdb file also in the same GAC folder. I am debugging an ASP.NET Application that uses the GAC dll as a reference. However it won't hit the breakpoints in my class library. Also it isnt showing any Debug.Write statements present in code. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Debug class is removed from release assembly code. How do you connect to the process? Did you restart the app after pdb files added?